# error in getting asp server element in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, getelementbyid

I am having problem to get `asp server element` data.
 Here is my `textbox` for usercode.
 and the script where i want to get its valu. but its not working.
 please help me in this.
 thnx in advance.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserCode" runat="server" Width="78%" Height="35%"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</asp:Content>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $("input[type='text']").change(function ()
      {            
          var textBox = document.getElementById('<%= txtUserCode.ClientID %>');
          alert(textBox);

     });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Which exactly error you got? Where is this script located (on a page or on a master page)

Comment: i got this alert ... [object HTMLInputElement] .... where i expect my input value. and the script is in the same aspx page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `alert(textBox.value);` instead of `alert(textBox)`